# protecting global variables during eval in Test::More

Tags: perl, error-handling, eval, test-more

I was scrolling through the code for Test::More because I wanted to see how `use_ok` and `require_ok` were implemented (and why Ovid doesn't like them). I came to the [`_eval`](https://github.com/schwern/test-more/blob/Test-Builder1.5/lib/Test/More.pm#L986) subroutine, which contains some special logic that I don't fully understand for protecting variables during an `eval` call. I understand from the documentation of [Try::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Try%3a%3aTiny#BACKGROUND) how difficult it is to deal with `$@`. However, I don't understand the handling of `$!` and `$SIG{__DIE__}` (below block copied verbatim):

```
# Work around oddities surrounding resetting of $@ by immediately
# storing it.
my( $sigdie, $eval_result, $eval_error );
{
    local( $@, $!, $SIG{__DIE__} );    # isolate eval
    $eval_result = eval $code;              ## no critic (BuiltinFunctions::ProhibitStringyEval)
    $eval_error  = $@;
    $sigdie      = $SIG{__DIE__} || undef;
}
# make sure that $code got a chance to set $SIG{__DIE__}
$SIG{__DIE__} = $sigdie if defined $sigdie;
```

The handling of `$SIG{__DIE__}` is related to [RT #34065](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=34065), but I still don't get it. Why is it necessary to set the variable again in that last line, since it should always get set in the last line of the block? If the whole point of these lines is to set the variable to whatever it became in the `eval` call, why does it have to be localized in the first place?

Also, if using `eval` without clobbering error vars means localizing both `$@` and `$!`, do we not also have to localize `$?`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like `$sigdie` is there to explictily allow the eval'd code to *set* `$SIG{__DIE__}`, while not allowing any externally set handler to take effect during the eval.

So the localization suppresses the external value, but requires saving any set value before the end of the block and setting it in the now not-localized version after the block.

I assume `$!` is localized but not `$?`, `$^E`, etc. for practical reasons (that is, I'd guess people complained about `$!` changing, but not anything else).

Comment: why would you want to disallow the caller's explicitly set `$SIG{__DIE__}` from taking effect?

Comment: because due to a bad early design decision in perl, the `__DIE__` handler is triggered by any exception, even one being caught by an eval.  because the test framework is dealing some exceptions, they should not also affect code outside the framework.